# Removing trim from a recessed can

Tags: light-fixture, trim, recessed-lighting

I am attempting to remove the trim from a recessed can. The image below is looking into the fixture at the socket.

[image]

Circled in red are two tabs that seem to hold the socket into the trim. In blue, these tab-like pieces appear to be riveted to the trim and don't move much, if at all.

I've tried pulling down on the trim, but there is a good amount of resistance, so I've hesitated on adding more downward force.

Are there any ideas on how this trim releases from the can?

Comment: Push the tabs in the red circles in toward the center of the socket and turn the trim clock-wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good chance those clips only hold the socket in the trim. The trim may be "sprung" into place by 2 bent wires that hold the trim up by the wire spreading out into guides. A little hard to explain, but the simplest way to check if that is the case, pull down on the edge of the trim. Unless paint is holding it, the trim should start to come down. It may feel like it wants to go back up but that is the springs doing their job. To finish removing the trim squeeze the 2 wires together and they will with some effort come out of their guides.

[image]

There may be a chance also there are spring steel grips holding it in place

[image]

These types are removed by starting to twist the trim so it over-rides the grip the to spring bars have on the side of the interior of the rough in housing.

Comment: ...and some of them have blades similar to the "spring grip" but they are hinged so they expand clockwise and shrink counterclockwise, so try counterclockwise if turning.